# Overwriting serializer with request data including nulls for absent keys

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

Let's imagine there is a `serializer` like this:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = (
            'title',
            'description'
        )
```

Where `description` is nullable. What I want is that the request data completely overwrite the serializer data on PUT request (when updating an existing model instance obviously). If I do:

```
event_serializer = EventSerializer(event, data=request_data)
```

It does overwrite everything, but it doesn't nullify `description` if it is absent from the request. Is there a way to do that without doing manually:

```
data['description'] = data.get('description', None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to define the `description` field on the serializer and use `default` like:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    # Use proper field type here instead of CharField
    description = serializers.CharField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = (
            'title',
            'description'
        )
```

See the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as well:

> **default**
>
> If set, this gives the default value that will be used for the
> field if no input value is supplied. If not set the default behavior
> is to not populate the attribute at all.
>
> May be set to a function or other callable, in which case the value
> will be evaluated each time it is used.
>
> Note that setting a default value implies that the field is not
> required. Including both the default and required keyword arguments is
> invalid and will raise an error.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I've been looking for.